# Como a variável p funciona nesse código?

Tags: python, while, iterator

Eu não sei como a variável `p` do *loop* `while` está trabalhando nesse código.

Se a variável `p` é a variável de iteração, porque o exercício também utiliza uma variável `p` dentro do `while` para armazenar o `s.find( "tigre", p )`?

Isso não causaria conflito? Falo isso porque o mesmo nome de variável que está sendo usado  para fazer a iteração, é o mesmo nome que está sendo usado para armazenar o `s.find( "tigre", p )` na primeira linha do `while`.

Como estes `p` estão funcionando?

```
s = "um tigre, dois tigres, três tigres"

p=0
while (p > -1):
    p = s.find("tigre", p)
    if p >= 0:
        print("Posição: %d" % p)
        p += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independente da linguagem, o 'p' vai ser o índice da palavra tigre, se não houver mais ocorrências da palavra, vai sair do loop.

```
s = "um tigre, dois tigres, três tigres"

p=0 #p inicia com 0 pra entrar no laço
while (p > -1):
    p = s.find("tigre", p) #busca o índice de tigre, a partir da posição p
    if p >= 0: #se encontrou, imprime o índice
        print("Posição: %d" % p)
        p += 1 #incrementa o índice da última ocorrência encontrada para não repetir a palavra
```

Comment: o que eu não entendi foi por que foi definida uma variável de nome p abaixo da linha do while, ou seja, (p = ) que tem o mesmo nome da variável de iteração, ou seja, não deveria dar erro?,por que se a variável (p) já é o nome da variável de iteração, como que o programa aceita a mesma variável (p) a receber s.find( "tigre", p ) ?, sendo que o p dentro do find() representa a variável de iteração?

Comment: ela está recebendo o valor retornado pela função find, dentro do while se não houver alteração do p em nenhum momento, ficaria em um loop infinito

Answer (score 7):

O segundo parâmetro da função `find` define o deslocamento em relação ao texto. Isto é, `s.find("tigre", 0)` buscará a primeira ocorrência da palavra "tigre" a partir da posição 0 de `s`, já `s.find("tigre", 10)` buscará a primeira ocorrência da palavra a partir da posição 10 de `s`. O que o programa faz é atualizar o valor deste deslocamento para que a mesma ocorrência da palavra não seja considerada mais de uma vez.

### TL;DR

Nosso texto:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   ...
```

O valor de `p` inicial é 0, portanto:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   ...
  ^
  p
```

Enquanto `p` for maior que -1, execute o *loop*. O novo valor de `p` será o retorno da posição onde for encontrado a palavra `tigre` no texto, com um deslocamento de `p`. Como `p` é zero, a função irá procurar a partir da posição 0 do texto, localizando a palavra na posição 3. Então, o novo valor de `p` será 3.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   ...
              ^
              p
```

Após exibido na tela, `p` é incrementado em 1:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   4  ...
                  ^
                  p
```

Na próxima iteração, a função `find` procurará pela palavra no texto a partir da posição `p`, que vale 4, então ele nçao considerará mais a primeira ocorrência da palavra. O novo valor de `p`, neste caso, será de 15.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  ...
                                                              ^
                                                              p
```

Novamente, ao ser exibido na tela, o valor de `p` é incrementado em 1.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  ...
                                                                  ^
                                                                  p
```

Na próxima iteração, a função `find` tentará localizar a palavra `tigre` no texto original, mas apenas a partir da posição 16, desconsiderando as duas primeiras ocorrências. Desta forma, o novo valor de `p` será 28.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
                                                                                                                  ^
                                                                                                                  p
```

Após exibido em tela, novamente o valor de `p` é incrementado em 1:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| u | m |   | t | i | g | r | e | , |   | d | o | i | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s | , |   | t | r | ê | s |   | t | i | g | r | e | s |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
                                                                                                                      ^ 
                                                                                                                      p
```

Finalmente, na última iteração, a função `find` buscará pela palavra `tigre` a partir da posição 29. Como não há mais ocorrências da palavra, é retornado -1, portanto `p` valerá -1, fazendo com que a condição do *while* seja desfeita e o programa se encerre.

Comment: Bah, muito bom.

Comment: que disposição! parabéns =]

Comment: cara, você MITOU na resposta, meme thug life pra você, hahaha

Answer (score 3):

Veja abaixo o código comentado:

```
s = "um tigre, dois tigres, três tigres"

p=0 #inicializa a variável com 0
while (p > -1): #enquanto o p for maior do que -1
   #Se encontrar tigre na string retorna a posição
   #Se não encontrar retorna -1
   p = s.find("tigre", p) 
   if p >= 0: #se p maior ou igual a zero encontrou na string
      print("Posição: %d" % p) # imprime a posição
      p += 1
```

[Veja mais sobre a função find](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)